# When declaring an object literal, are keys evaluated in order?

Tags: javascript

I'm declaring an object literal like

```
object = { a: func1(), b: func2() }
```

`func1` **has** to be executed **before** `func2`.

Are `func1` and `func2` **guaranteed** to be executed in the order *they're called* in the object declaration?

Comment: LOL, just came back to mark that same duplicate, having found it.

Comment: Short answer: Yes, it's guaranteed. The property initializers are executed in source code order.